# Intuition behind storing the remainders?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve a question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/continuous-subarray-sum/description/):

> Given a list of non-negative numbers and a target integer k, write a function to check if the array has a continuous subarray of size at least 2 that sums up to the multiple of k, that is, sums up to n*k where n is also an integer.  For e.g., if `[23, 2, 4, 6, 7]`,  `k=6`, then the output should be `True`, since `[2, 4]` is a continuous subarray of size 2 and sums up to 6.

I am trying to understand the following [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/continuous-subarray-sum/discuss/99506/Concise-C++-solution-use-set-instead-of-map):

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool checkSubarraySum(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        int n = nums.size(), sum = 0, pre = 0;
        unordered_set<int> modk;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            sum += nums[i];
            int mod = k == 0 ? sum : sum % k;
            if (modk.count(mod)) return true;
            modk.insert(pre);
            pre = mod;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

I understand that we are trying to store: `0, (a/k), (a+b)/k, (a+b+c)/k`, etc. into the hashSet (where `k`!=`0`) and that we do that in the *next* iteration since we want the subarray size to be at least `2`.

But, how does this guarantee that we get a subarray whose elements sum up to `k`?  What mathematical property guarantees this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set `modk` is gradually populated with  all sums (considered modulo k) of contiguous sub-arrays starting at the beginning of the array.

The key observation is that:

> a-b = n*k for some natural n iff
>   a-b ≡ 0 mod k iff 
>    a ≡ b mod k

so if a contiguous sub-array nums[i_0]..nums[i_1], sums up to 0 modulo k, then the two sub-arrays nums[0]..nums[i_0]  and nums[i_0 + 1]..nums[i_1] have the *same sum* modulo k.

Thus it's enough if two distinct sub-arrays *starting at the beginning of the array* have the same sum, modulo k.

Luckily, there are only k such values, so you only need to use a set of size k.

Some nitpicks:

- if n > k, you're going to have an appropriate sub-array anyway (the [pigeon-hole principle](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Pigeonhole_Principle)), so the loop will actually never iterate more than k+1 times.
- There should not be any sort of class involved here, that makes no sense.
- contiguous, not continuous. Arrays and sub-arrays are discrete and can't be continuous...

Comment: Sorry.. But my math might be too bad.  When you say, `0 mod k` in the equation, you mean just `k`, right?

Comment: No. Note I use the equivalence sign, not equality

Comment: From [what I understand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111330/explain-for-students-why-does-0-mod-n-equal-0-zero), `0 modulo k = 0`.  So, when you say `i_0...i_1, sums up to 0` then the sums of the subarrays `0..i_0 and (i_0 + 1)..i_1 sum up to` 0?  Sorry, again! :)

Answer (score 0):

module base k of sum is equivalent to the module k of sum of the modules base k

(a+b)%k  = (a%k + b%k) % k

(23 + 2) % 6 = 1
( (23%6) + (2%6) ) % 6  = (5 + 2) % 6 = 1

modk stores all modules that you calculated iteratively. If at iteration i you get a repeated module calculated at  i-m  that means that you added a subsequence of m elements which sum is multiple of k

```
 i=0 nums[0] = 23     sum = 23    sum%6 = 5     modk = [5]
 i=1 nums[1] = 2      sum = 25    sum%6 = 1     modk = [5, 1]
 i=2 nums[2] = 4      sum = 29    sum%6 = 5     5 already exists in modk (4+2)%6 =0
```